# A series convergence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

What is the closed-form answer for this series(if there is):
$$f(z)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{z^n}{n^2(n+1)}$$ assuming $z$ is a complex number and $|z|<1$. 
I have looked for some approximating fitting functions, but I think there must be an exact answer too!

Comment: You will need the [polylog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm).

Answer (score 1):

Since
$$\frac 1{n^2(n+1)}=\frac{1}{n^2}+\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n}$$
this is the infinite series of
$$f(z)=\frac{z-1 }{z}\log (1-z)+\text{Li}_2(z)-1$$

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach is to differentiate $$zf'(z)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{z^n}{n(n+1)}$$
$$(zf')'=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{z^{n-1}}{n+1}=-\frac{\ln(1-z)+z}{z^2}$$
Hence integrate twice to get an integral formula for $f(z)$; of course the polylog function will still appear in integral form.